# Retrieve values from getJSON() call in jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call in my jquery to my MVC controller:

```
$.getJSON('/mysite/controller/dosomething', { postId: id }, function (data) {
```

The 'data' that I am returning is in the form of a JsonResult, and consists of a simple custom object with 1 property called 'Message' and another property called 'Count'. Both of these values are assigned and I am returning them as follows (edited for brevity):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult DoSomething(int postId)
{
    var response = new MyAjaxResponseModel {Message = "Hello world!", Count = 66};
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In my jQuery, I then want to be able to look at both values in the Json response, but I don't know the proper way to get at these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.Message`, `data.Count` in the callback you're passing to `$.getJSON()`? To inspect the structure of your `data` object, you can use `console.log(data)` (also, in that callback)